# Adding "\0" to a subset range end

Tags: java, set, subset

Directly from this [java api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html):

Why adding a "\0" would "open" one range end as explained in the following quote? 
I checked the "\0" escape sequence and it says it represents the null character.
What is the null character in terms of Strings? and why adding to the "high parameter" of a subset should give the parameter itself included in the range?

> If you need a closed range (which includes both endpoints), and the
>   element type allows for calculation of the successor of a given value,
>   merely request the subrange from lowEndpoint to
>   successor(highEndpoint). For example, suppose that s is a sorted set
>   of strings. The following idiom obtains a view containing all of the
>   strings in s from low to high, inclusive:
>
> SortedSet sub = s.subSet(low, high+"\0");

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: In few words: Why s.subSet(low, high+"\0"); should include the high index in the range? what does adding "\0" implies? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call subset with a high and a low limit, the *high limit element will not be included* (ie `low <= element < high` will be included, but that excludes `high`).

If you want it included, you need to give a limit *slightly higher, but not high enough to include another element*.

The easiest way to make the next bigger string is to append a `\0`, since making it longer will make it sort just after the high limit (so the high limit element is included), but it's not possible to find another string that sorts between them, so there's no risk of inadvertently including an extra element.

Answer (score 3):

`high+"\0"` is a way to obtaining the String that would be sorted immediately after `high`.

So, if you want a subset that includes the `high` element, you need to specify the limit to the subset as `high+"\0"`

For example, if you were dealing with a `SortedSet<Int>` and you wanted the subset between 4 and 8, both inclusive, you would use `s.subSet(4, 8+1)`. `high+"\0"` is the String equivalent.